# GUI test for native android and iOS applications

Tags: android, ios, user-interface, native, gui-testing

I have a native android and a native iOS application and want to test them both with one tool.

Is there a tool which makes it possible to **record/write** a GUI test once and use it then for both platforms?

The only tool I found was MonkeyTalk but aren´t there more tools out there?

Comment: That should be impossible, simply because the UI of the iOS application should not be identical to the UI of the Android application.

Comment: From the MonkeyTalk FAQ/documentation: 
_Is it cross-platform? Can I record on iOS and playback on Android? [..]
Yes. If you have logically identical apps on iOS and Android, you should be able to record tests against one OS and play them back on another. [...] For example, Android apps have typically have tabs on the top of the screen and iOS apps have tabs on the bottom, but as long as they both have the same tabs recording on either OS would record TabBar.Select, and playback on either OS would work as intended._ 
So i thought there must be more such tools? :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Robotium. 
Download the tool from this location: http://code.google.com/p/scirocco/wiki/QuickStartScirocco

Scirocco (the tool referred in the above link) is just an Add-On to the Robotium. It means Scirocco enables you to capture images. Almost same as Monkey Runner.

Checkout a simple example at this location:
http://testdroid.com/tech/54/automated-ui-testing-android-applications-robotium

Hope this helps!